# Dynamic Watermark - Command failed: gm convert: Unable to read font

Tags: node.js

I need the image with the watermark so I am using "dynamic-watermark" node module. While I am starting the app, I get the issue please see below

```
{ Error: Command failed: gm convert: Unable to read font (n019003l.pfb) [No such file or directory].
at ChildProcess.onExit (E:\Development\NodeJs\npm-modules\dynamic-watermark\node_modules\gm\lib\command.js:301:17)
at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
at ChildProcess.cp.emit (E:\Development\NodeJs\npm-modules\dynamic-watermark\node_modules\gm\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:29)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5) code: 1, signal: null }
```

Comment: After install `brew install imagemagick`, `brew install graphicsmagick` and`brew install ghostscript` on my machine, it started to work.

Comment: I am using the windows system. And I have installed all the three modules